# Removing duplicates from a list generated with Findall

Tags: list, email, prolog, duplicates, prolog-findall

I'm practicing Prolog by coming up with a very simple database of who has sent and received emails.

I have created a list using `findall` of the receivers of a pre-specified `X`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to use your list/2:

```
all_receivers(X,Uniques) :- findall(Y,(email(X,Y)),List),list(List,Uniques).
```

but the easiest way is sort/2, or better setof/3

```
all_receivers(X,List) :- setof(Y,X^(email(X,Y)),List).
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Could you please just explain the list(List,Uniques part)?

Comment: Just provides a fresh variable where to put the cleared content. Prolog variables cannot be 'assigned'...

Comment: No need for brackets in `X^(email(X,Y))`.